# Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, xmlhttprequest, domexception

I am getting the below error.

> Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11

Here is the code where I am getting Error RUN TIME.

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/xhtml+xml");<br>
xhttp.open("POST",xmlFile,true);<br>
xhttp.send(postData);
```

I tried with `false` in the third parameter of xhttp.open.
Can anyone tell me what's causing this?

Comment: Are you sending your request to the same server that served the page?  Remember CORS!

Comment: My request is going on two server. One is our server (middle layer) and second one is expedia Server(a hotel booking API). Our middle layer sends further to expedia and return response to us.

Answer (score 22):

The error comes from the order of execution:

```
xhttp.open("POST",xmlFile,true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/xhtml+xml");
xhttp.send(postData);
```

You must first open the connection and then set the request header otherwise you will get the error.

Comment: Hi, Anonymous    Your order of above code is perfect. Now my code is working fine. Thanks a Lot.

Comment: Man, I'm not sure why, but in chrome, it didn't care which order I had set the headers. When it came to headless browser testing with phantomjs, it blew up! Thanks a bunch! I literally was banging my head against my desk all day.

Answer (score 1):

The `XMLHttpRequest::Status` is unavailable till the `XMLHttpRequest::readyState` has changed to `4` ie. a proper response has been acquired from the server and has now been populated in the `Status` variable.

Thus accessing the XMLHttpRequest::Status early can result in this error.

Solution: first verify `readyState` and only upon success — access `Status`

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
{
    switch (xmlhttp.status)
    {
    case 200: // Do the Do
        break;
    case 404: // Error: 404 - Resource not found!
        break;
    default:  // Error: Unknown!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Socket has not be configure/initialize/opened connection and send has been called